# Keypair with Shellinabox?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I've got an Amazon EC2 instance with a keypair, and I want to setup shellinabox so I can ssh from any web browser. However, shellinabox only seems to allow password logins and I wasn't able to find any way to enable logins with a keypair.

Does shellinabox allow login with a keypair?

**EDIT: Ignoring security concerns for the moment (say this is within a trusted network)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shell in a Box](https://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) has nothing to do with SSH, so key-pairing is not possible.

If you really NEED to SSH to a system and you have web access, you should be able to go the extra step to run a proper SSH client like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Answer (score 4):

Shellinabox is not an ssh client, it is a web application that emulates a plain Unix terminal. In particular, it has **absolutely no security** at all. In fact, using it is even *worse* than simply allowing insecure telnet! This is because all logins from shellinabox are logged in utmp as coming from 127.0.0.1 and thus attacks (of which you will get **many**) become diffcult or impossible to trace.

This is not software you should *ever* run on the public Internet for *any* reason.

Comment: Are you suuuuure? I know of [*certain* companies](http://producepro.com) that advocate and endorse the use of [Shell-In-A-Box](https://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) on the public internet. :)

Comment: Yeah, and how long did it take for their customers to get compromised? Minutes, was it?

Comment: ***14 minutes...*** Shell-In-A-Box is absurdly insecure.